# If and Or syntax wrong

Tags: if-statement, syntax, stata

What do I need to change so that the `binaryeducation` variable always==0 for this regression? The "or" should only be for the scenarios

```
svy: reg binaryanswer1 i.scenario if scenario==5 | scenario==9 | scenario==12 | scenario==14 | scenario==15 & binaryeducation==0
```

Answer (score 1):

See

```
help operator
```

for the precedence of operators. I have never memorised this either on purpose or by accident. If the order of operators is not what you want, use parentheses to enforce a different order. I think what you want is

```
if (scenario==5 | scenario==9 | scenario==12 | scenario==14 | scenario==15) & binaryeducation==0
```

and indeed another device would solve the problem more neatly:

```
if inlist(scenario, 5, 9, 12, 14, 15) & binaryeducation == 0
```